# how to get distinct record from table field in Amazon CloudSearch

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

hi i am new to Amazon CloudSearch.in mysql we are using Distinct keyword  to get  unique records.how to use this feature in  Amazon CloudSearch..please help me

Answer (score 0):

Cloudsearch doesn't have the ability to do a "DISTINCT" query in the same way that a SQL database would, i.e. return the values of some specified fields with no duplicates.

Cloudsearch always returns at least the IDs of all of the documents that match your search criteria.

If you are looking for a specific document, and you have its document ID, you can retrieve it like:

```
.../2011-02-01/search?bq=docid:'mydocid'
```

Otherwise, you'll need to have a field in the document that is unique, enforced by your application, that you can search by.